# How do I convert a string to a decimal in unity javascript?

Tags: type-conversion

How do I convert a string to a decimal in unity javascript?

Comment: Could you please edit your question title to be more descriptive, like "How to convert string to decimal in Unity JavaScript"?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean javascript in Unity 3D?

If you are: Unity uses Mono, so you should have access to **`float.Parse(str)`** or  **`decimal.Parse(str)`**. 
(Or the qualified names **`System.Single.Parse(str)`** or **`System.Decimal.Parse(str)`**)